# Pasting into text file without quotes

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing a script that copies from cells to test file (.sql)

Everytime I create a new file the resulte is in doublequotes, and it's unacceptable, because it has to be an SQL script and with quotes it wouldn't work.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim saveFile As String
Dim WorkRng As Range

Sheets("TU").Columns(10).Copy

Sheets("TU").Columns(11).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

On Error Resume Next

Set WorkRng = Range("K3:K20")

Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Add
WorkRng.Copy
wb.Worksheets(1).Paste
saveFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(fileFilter:="Text Files (*.sql), *.sql")

wb.SaveAs Filename:=saveFile, FileFormat:=xlTextWindows, CreateBackup:=False
wb.Close

End Sub
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Checked this and this doesn't show as in single quotes for me. Do the original values of each cell contain single quotes?

If that is the case then you can try a Loop on the cells and replace each quote after you paste the values into column K.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim saveFile As String
Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim cell As Range, rng As Range
Set rng = Range("K:K")

Sheets("TU").Columns(10).Copy

Sheets("TU").Columns(11).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

For Each cell In rng

    If cell.Value = "" Then
     Exit For
    End If

    If InStr(1, cell.Value, "'") > 0 Then
        cell.Value = Replace(cell.Value, "'", "")
    End If
Next cell


On Error Resume Next

Set WorkRng = Range("K3:K20")

Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Add
WorkRng.Copy
wb.Worksheets(1).Paste
saveFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(fileFilter:="Text Files (*.sql), *.sql")

wb.SaveAs Filename:=saveFile, FileFormat:=xlTextWindows, CreateBackup:=False
wb.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: No, it doens't work, It still gives me an answer wit double quotes :/

Comment: What are your input values when testing? Meaning what are the values in Column J?